# Bound moments wrt. known initial and final moments

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $X$ be an $L^p$ random variable, where $p\in (0,1)$ and $W_t$ usual Brownian motion (with $W_t$ independent from $X$). I'd like to bound
$$\mathbb E|X+W_t|^p$$
purely in terms of $\mathbb E|X|^p$ and $\mathbb E|X+W_1|^p$ (which I can assume to exist).

I was able to show the following, which looks a bit similar, but this does not solve my problem: For $X,Y\in L^p$, I can bound
$$\begin{align*}\mathbb E|X + tY|^p &= \mathbb E|(1-t)X + t(X+Y)|^p \leq \mathbb E(\max\{|X|^p, |X+Y|^p\}) \leq \mathbb E[|X|^p + |X+Y|^p] \\
&= \mathbb E|X|^p + \mathbb E|X+Y|^p\end{align*}$$
(first inequality by quasiconvexity of the p-norm). This is essentially the kind of bound I would like to obtain. But of course, $W_t \neq t Y$ for a random variable $Y$, so I cannot directly apply this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $Y:=W_1$ and $t\in[0,1]$, the expectation in question is
$$
\begin{aligned}
E|X+\sqrt t\,Y|^p&=E|(1-\sqrt t)X+\sqrt t\,(X+Y)|^p \\ 
&\le(1-\sqrt t)^p E|X|^p+(\sqrt t)^p E|X+Y|^p \\
&\le E|X|^p+E|X+Y|^p \\
&=E|X|^p+E|X+W_1|^p.  \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: But $W_t \neq \sqrt t W_1$, so I don't understand why the first term is valid.

Comment: $W_t$ has the same distribution as $\sqrt t W_1$.

Comment: And I can just swap random variables out with other ones having the same distribution? I am worried that I can't do that here because the path of $W_t$ and $\sqrt t W_1$ are very different.

Comment: And, also, why does $E|(1-\sqrt t)X+\sqrt t\,(X+Y)|^p \le(1-\sqrt t)^p E|X|^p+(\sqrt t)^p E|X+Y|^p$ hold? For $p<1$ we do not have the Minkowski inequality, right?

Comment: @MercuryBench : (i) The path here is quite irrelevant. The expectation of a given function of **two** random variables (r.v.'s) (here of $X$ and $W_t$) depends only on the joint distribution of the r.v.'s. In this case, $X$ is independent of each $W_t$, so that the joint distribution of $X$ and $W_t$ is determined by the individual distributions of $X$ and of $W_t$. Also, $W_t$ has the same distribution as $\sqrt t\,W_1$. So, the joint distribution of $X$ and $W_t$ is the same as that of $X$ and $\sqrt t\,W_1$. So, $E|X+W_t|^p=E|X+\sqrt t\,W_1|^p=E|X+\sqrt t\,Y|^p$.

Comment: (ii) The inequality $E|(1-\sqrt t)X+\sqrt t\,(X+Y)|^p\le(1-\sqrt t)^p E|X|^p+(\sqrt t)^p E|X+Y|^p$ follows from the inequality $(a+b)^p\le a^p+b^p$ for $p\in(0,1]$ and nonnegative $a,b$, and standard properties of the expectation.